# Add radio button to a UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, radio-button, ibaction

I am facing a problem with custom radio button on cell in `UItableViewView` i'm using below code and I want to set the same action for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and radio button sender action so that I can select one cell from all and deselect all other cells in table view. In the tableView I want to display all iPod music library songs where users can select one from all at a time.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell_Connections";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        }
```

`cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cbimg_unselected.png"];

    MPMediaItem *temp1 = [self.sectionedArtistsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [temp1 valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44, 41);
    button.frame = frame;

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cbimg_unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cbimg_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    return cell;
}

- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tblVwMusic];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblVwMusic indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        //[self tableView: self.tblVwMusic accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

    for (int section = 0, sectionCount = tblVwMusic.numberOfSections; section < sectionCount; ++section) {
        for (int row = 0, rowCount = [tblVwMusic numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row < rowCount; ++row) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tblVwMusic cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
            [tblVwMusic deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section] animated:YES];
            NSArray *btnsArray = [cell.contentView subviews];
            for (UIButton *but in btnsArray) {
                if ([but isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                    [but setSelected:NO];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!button.selected) {
        button.selected = button.selected;

    }else {

        button.selected = !button.selected;
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for (int section = 0, sectionCount = tableView.numberOfSections; section < sectionCount; ++section) {
        for (int row = 0, rowCount = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row < rowCount; ++row) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section] animated:YES];
            NSArray *btnsArray = [cell.contentView subviews];
            for (UIButton *but in btnsArray) {
                if ([but isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                    [but setSelected:NO];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *btnsArray = [cell.contentView subviews];

    for (UIButton *but in btnsArray) {
        if ([but isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            if (!but.selected) {
                 [but setSelected:YES];
            } else {
                [but setSelected:NO];
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: What exactly problem you are facing now, are you facing UI problem or Logic that how to select one row at one time?

Comment: actually this is a logic problem where user have two option one for didselectrowatindexpath and another is radio button selector. i have to choose same for both condition at a time.

Comment: can u help me for http://stackoverflow.com/q/13560476/1705912 for add fade and flip effect in video